# How to store an Inputstream (image) into Google App Engine Blobstore using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

The tutorials for using the Blobstore all seem to demonstrate storing data by using a HTML POST form.

**POST to the upload URL:**

```
<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would like to upload the file using the server. (Java) Is there an API for this? or do I have to manually get the upload url, and POST server-side using HttpURLConnection?

```
 URL url = new URL(blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload"));
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Answer (score 2):

On the server-side you can simply store data in blobstore [via the File API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore).

**Update:** [File API has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore) as of Nov 2013. If you need to create large blobs programatically you should use [Google Cloud Storage Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) instead.

Comment: This is not ideal, since it is experimental, but I will give it a try.

Comment: We use it already about 9 months and it works without a problem.

Comment: @PeterKnego - GCS is for large files. What if I want an API to store small files?

Comment: @kilaka - the size does not matter, there is no minimum size limit. However, if your data is less then 1Mb, you can choose to store it into Datastore as `Text` property or `Blob` property.